# IE8 problems with .animate() of opacity property - descendant remains opaque throughout

Tags: jquery, css, opacity, internet-explorer-8

Basically I have something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a>
<div class="trigger-layer"></div>
<div class="title-layer">Text here</div>
<div class="hover-layer"></div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I use jQuery to animate the `<ul>` as follow:

```
$ul = xxx (where I assign the selector to var $ul)
$ul.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {$ul.css("display", "none")});
```

However in IE8, as the `<ul>` fades off, the `<div class="title-layer">Text here</div>` remains clear and opaque. Finally the animation ends, the `display: none;` property is applied onto the `<ul>` and the text disappears aburptly.

Answer (score 1):

You have some external markup/styling/script going on here affecting this, using *only* what you posted works, you can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/r7pwQ/

Are you sure there's no invalid HTML going on? (besides the `<div>`s inside the anchor, which is invalid as well :)  [Make sure you're dealing with valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/), otherwise IE will do all sorts of random things.

Comment: But there is no other way I can accomplish what I need within the scope of my technical expertise as of now :(

Comment: You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VHNvh/ animation is slowed to 5000ms so I can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: @Fabian - There are a *lot* of extra divs there...may I ask why you're trying to write a menu anyway?  (The problem is the relative position on the title div, though there are complicating factors with all your z-indexes).  There are existing menus that do what you're after, e.g. [superfish for the style you have](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)

Comment: So `position: relative;` is what causes the problem with IE 8? For the record IE 7 renders the font really weird, like it's blotchy and pixelated. Well that menu is generated by Wordpress's native `wp_list_pages()` function, so I have limited control over the tags used. Inserting `<div>` into the anchor tag is the only way I can come up with.